# I can't execute SQL queries with some joins in a Drupal database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, drupal, mariadb

I am working in a Drupal 10 project and I am making a dynamic query with this code:

```
$query = $this->entityTypeManager->getStorage('node')->getQuery();
$query->accessCheck(FALSE);
$query->condition('status', 1);
$query->condition('type', $node_bundle); 
$query->condition($taxonomy_field_name, $node_term_id);
$query->condition('nid', $node->id(), '<>');
$orGroup = $query->orConditionGroup();

foreach($recurrences as $recurrence){

    $date_start = $recurrence['value'];
    $date_end = $recurrence['end_value'];

    $andGroup = $query->andConditionGroup();

    $andGroup->condition($smart_date_field_name . '.end_value', $date_start, '>');
    $andGroup->condition($smart_date_field_name . '.value', $date_end, '<');

    $orGroup->condition($andGroup);

}

$query->condition($orGroup);
$nodes_id = $query->execute();
```

Depending of the number of $recurrences the query has more or less joins.

Using dpm($query->__toString()), the query that I obtain is:

```
SELECT base_table.vid AS vid, base_table.nid AS nid
FROM
node base_table
INNER JOIN node_field_data node_field_data ON node_field_data.nid = base_table.nid
INNER JOIN node__field_reserva_sala_sala node__field_reserva_sala_sala ON node__field_reserva_sala_sala.entity_id = base_table.nid
LEFT JOIN node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora ON node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora.entity_id = base_table.nid
LEFT JOIN node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_2 ON node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_2.entity_id = base_table.nid
LEFT JOIN node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_3 ON node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_3.entity_id = base_table.nid
LEFT JOIN node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_4 ON node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_4.entity_id = base_table.nid
LEFT JOIN node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_5 ON node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_5.entity_id = base_table.nid
LEFT JOIN node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_6 ON node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_6.entity_id = base_table.nid
LEFT JOIN node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_7 ON node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_7.entity_id = base_table.nid
LEFT JOIN node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_8 ON node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_8.entity_id = base_table.nid
LEFT JOIN node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_9 ON node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_9.entity_id = base_table.nid
LEFT JOIN node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_10 ON node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_10.entity_id = base_table.nid
LEFT JOIN node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_11 ON node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_11.entity_id = base_table.nid
LEFT JOIN node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_12 ON node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_12.entity_id = base_table.nid
LEFT JOIN node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_13 ON node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_13.entity_id = base_table.nid
LEFT JOIN node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_14 ON node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_14.entity_id = base_table.nid
LEFT JOIN node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_15 ON node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_15.entity_id = base_table.nid
LEFT JOIN node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_16 ON node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_16.entity_id = base_table.nid
LEFT JOIN node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_17 ON node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_17.entity_id = base_table.nid
LEFT JOIN node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_18 ON node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_18.entity_id = base_table.nid
LEFT JOIN node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_19 ON node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_19.entity_id = base_table.nid
LEFT JOIN node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_20 ON node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_20.entity_id = base_table.nid
LEFT JOIN node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_21 ON node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_21.entity_id = base_table.nid
WHERE (node_field_data.status = '1') AND (node_field_data.type = 'reserva_sala') AND (node__field_reserva_sala_sala.field_reserva_sala_sala_target_id = '17') AND (node_field_data.nid <> '77') AND (((node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora.field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_end_value > '1681284600') and (node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora.field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_value < '1681290000')) or ((node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_2.field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_end_value > '1681889400') and (node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_2.field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_value < '1681894800')) or ((node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_3.field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_end_value > '1682494200') and (node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_3.field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_value < '1682499600')) or ((node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_4.field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_end_value > '1683099000') and (node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_4.field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_value < '1683104400')) or ((node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_5.field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_end_value > '1683703800') and (node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_5.field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_value < '1683709200')) or ((node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_6.field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_end_value > '1684308600') and (node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_6.field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_value < '1684314000')) or ((node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_7.field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_end_value > '1684913400') and (node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_7.field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_value < '1684918800')) or ((node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_8.field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_end_value > '1685518200') and (node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_8.field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_value < '1685523600')) or ((node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_9.field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_end_value > '1686123000') and (node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_9.field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_value < '1686128400')) or ((node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_10.field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_end_value > '1686727800') and (node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_10.field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_value < '1686733200')) or ((node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_11.field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_end_value > '1687332600') and (node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_11.field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_value < '1687338000')) or ((node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_12.field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_end_value > '1687937400') and (node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_12.field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_value < '1687942800')) or ((node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_13.field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_end_value > '1688542200') and (node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_13.field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_value < '1688547600')) or ((node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_14.field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_end_value > '1689147000') and (node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_14.field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_value < '1689152400')) or ((node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_15.field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_end_value > '1689751800') and (node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_15.field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_value < '1689757200')) or ((node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_16.field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_end_value > '1690356600') and (node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_16.field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_value < '1690362000')) or ((node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_17.field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_end_value > '1690961400') and (node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_17.field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_value < '1690966800')) or ((node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_18.field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_end_value > '1691566200') and (node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_18.field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_value < '1691571600')) or ((node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_19.field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_end_value > '1692171000') and (node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_19.field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_value < '1692176400')) or ((node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_20.field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_end_value > '1692775800') and (node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_20.field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_value < '1692781200')) or ((node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_21.field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_end_value > '1693380600') and (node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_21.field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_value < '1693386000')))
```

When I execute that query with $query->execute() the database use all CPU and is not able to respond.
[image]

[image]

If I execute the same query with less joins it works fine and it retrieves values.

In addition, if I execute the same query on mysql client directly also I have the same problem.

Why it happens? Where could be the problem?

**Specs of my server**

- OS: Debian 11
- Web: Apache/2.4.56
- PHP: 8.1.17
- DB version: 10.5.18-MariaDB-0+deb11u1 (also I have tried with MySQL Server)
- DB Engine: InnoDB
- DB size: 34 MB
- Drupal: 10.0.7

EDIT:

The result that I have obtained with EXPLAIN:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  node__field_reserva_sala_sala   ref PRIMARY,field_reserva_sala_sala_target_id   field_reserva_sala_sala_target_id   4   const   8   Using index
1   SIMPLE  base_table  eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   calendari_d10.node__field_reserva_sala_sala.entity_id   1   
1   SIMPLE  node_field_data ref PRIMARY,node__id__default_langcode__langcode,node_field__type__target_id,node__status_type  node__status_type   39  const,const,calendari_d10.node__field_reserva_sala_sala.entity_id   1   Using where; Using index
1   SIMPLE  node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora    ref PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   calendari_d10.node__field_reserva_sala_sala.entity_id   1   
1   SIMPLE  node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_2  ref PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   calendari_d10.node__field_reserva_sala_sala.entity_id   1   
1   SIMPLE  node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_3  ref PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   calendari_d10.node__field_reserva_sala_sala.entity_id   1   
1   SIMPLE  node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_4  ref PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   calendari_d10.node__field_reserva_sala_sala.entity_id   1   
1   SIMPLE  node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_5  ref PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   calendari_d10.node__field_reserva_sala_sala.entity_id   1   
1   SIMPLE  node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_6  ref PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   calendari_d10.node__field_reserva_sala_sala.entity_id   1   
1   SIMPLE  node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_7  ref PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   calendari_d10.node__field_reserva_sala_sala.entity_id   1   
1   SIMPLE  node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_8  ref PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   calendari_d10.node__field_reserva_sala_sala.entity_id   1   
1   SIMPLE  node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_9  ref PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   calendari_d10.node__field_reserva_sala_sala.entity_id   1   
1   SIMPLE  node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_10 ref PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   calendari_d10.node__field_reserva_sala_sala.entity_id   1   
1   SIMPLE  node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_11 ref PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   calendari_d10.node__field_reserva_sala_sala.entity_id   1   
1   SIMPLE  node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_12 ref PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   calendari_d10.node__field_reserva_sala_sala.entity_id   1   
1   SIMPLE  node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_13 ref PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   calendari_d10.node__field_reserva_sala_sala.entity_id   1   
1   SIMPLE  node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_14 ref PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   calendari_d10.node__field_reserva_sala_sala.entity_id   1   
1   SIMPLE  node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_15 ref PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   calendari_d10.node__field_reserva_sala_sala.entity_id   1   
1   SIMPLE  node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_16 ref PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   calendari_d10.node__field_reserva_sala_sala.entity_id   1   
1   SIMPLE  node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_17 ref PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   calendari_d10.node__field_reserva_sala_sala.entity_id   1   
1   SIMPLE  node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_18 ref PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   calendari_d10.node__field_reserva_sala_sala.entity_id   1   
1   SIMPLE  node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_19 ref PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   calendari_d10.node__field_reserva_sala_sala.entity_id   1   
1   SIMPLE  node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_20 ref PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   calendari_d10.node__field_reserva_sala_sala.entity_id   1   
1   SIMPLE  node__field_reserva_sala_data_i_hora_21 ref PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   calendari_d10.node__field_reserva_sala_sala.entity_id   1   Using where
```

Comment: Could you post TEXT results of EXPLAIN SELECT sql_no_cache (rest of your long query):

Comment: I am not sure what the purpose of you statement is, but could it be a solution to take the minium $date_start and the maximum $date_end to reduce joins?

Comment: @h.m.i.13  Using google.com, search for 'MySQL EXPLAIN TUTORIAL' to see my purpose.  Any selection to reduce JOINS row volume will be a positive step, forever. Yes, reduce volume, every time you see an opportunity.  And do not forget SELECTIONS need indexes to quickly reduce table scans.

Comment: @WilsonHauck the purpose of EXPLAIN... is clear. My comment was targeting the statement/query in the question.

Comment: The purpose of my request for EXPLAIN was to determine WHERE you have no indexes.  EXPLAIN results make this task vary easy to identify.

Comment: @WilsonHauck I have edited and added at the end of the post what I have obtained with adding EXPLAIN at the beginning of the query.

Answer (score 0):

As you suggested me, I has been thinking that adding indexes in some columns could be the best solution, but could not be the best way because I consider that alter the Drupal database structure is not a clean solution. If somebody tries to install the module where it has this code, also they should know which indexes are necessari to work fine.

I have taken an alternative way. I split the query with small queries, where each query retrieves me a part of the solution.

```
$query = $this->entityTypeManager->getStorage('node')->getQuery();

$query->accessCheck(FALSE);
$query->condition('status', 1);
$query->condition('type', $node_bundle);
...

//Array where I save the result
$nodes_id = array();

//For each recurrence I make a query
foreach($recurrences as $recurrence){
    
    //Clone base query
    $sub_query = clone $query;
    
    //Get the timestamp start and end
    $date_start = $recurrence['value'];
    $date_end = $recurrence['end_value'];
    
    //Create AND condition
    $andGroup = $sub_query->andConditionGroup();
    $andGroup->condition($smart_date_field_name . '.end_value', $date_start, '>');
    $andGroup->condition($smart_date_field_name . '.value', $date_end, '<');
    
    //Add the condition into the query
    $sub_query->condition($andGroup);
    
    //Show the query
    //dpm($sub_query->__toString());
    
    //Execute the query and save the results into the array
    $nodes_id = array_merge($nodes_id, $sub_query->execute());
    
}

//Load the node objects from ids
$nodes = $this->entityTypeManager->getStorage('node')->loadMultiple($nodes_id);

return $nodes;
```

Perhaps is not the most elegant way, but it seems that this solution works.

Comment: Congratulatons.